# how can I correct the margin space in a journal manuscript?

Tags: margins

I have a problem with preparing the manuscript in the latex macro pachakge. I put the `svjour2.cls`. (Springer latex class) and `svglov2.clo` in the TEX file’s location. However, after execution, the final pdf file seems incorrect. I compared the final file to a sample paper in archive of applied mechanics journal and found some differences. For instance, the margins in top and bottom of the manuscript are too narrow and wide, respectively. Furthermore, the font size of figure’s captions and also references are equal to text body’ font size. I can’t change such parameters manually, and it should be done by the `svglov2.clo` file. I execute the template file in the macro package, which is available in the journal’s home page and it has the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you have an up-to-date version of the class and settings, and that it is being used by LaTeX then I'm not sure you should do anything. The way the question reads, that does appear to be the case.

The reason I say you shouldn't do anything is that it's very common for 'production' versions of journals not to be simply typeset from the sources supplied by the authors. As such, you cannot know if the formatting differences are deliberate, but can only make sure you'd done what the editorial office have asked of you.